# How to change the edges lines in edit mode after smooth?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, smooth

I am using Blender 3.0.1. I created a humanoid model.

I used subdivision surface to smooth the whole model. Then I want to edit the model again after the smooth. But in edit mode, the lines are still in poly (before using subdivision).

My question is how can I change the "edit mode" lines into the smooth surface model???

[image]

Comment: You need to apply the modifier first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.